# How return to the first view

Tags: cocoa-touch

This could be a dumb question, but men, I'm newbie on iPhone-sdk.

I walk deep 5 views. Now, in the view #5 finish the workflow, but how return back to the first view?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Give us a bit more information about your code.

Comment: Yeah, was using UINavigationController. The marked answer work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really give enough information. Are you using a UINavigationController? If so -- right in the documentation, I might add -- is the method:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```